# For loop to excute a php code error

Tags: php

i'm using this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php to do this

```
$options = getopt(array('c::'), array('chunk::'));
var_dump($options);
```

this code located in a file called do.php and i using this shell command to print the result

```
for i in `seq 2`;do php /home/user/public_html/do.php --chunk=$i ;done
```

the result is

```
array(2) {
  ["chunk"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  ["chunk"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

how that happend? it should

```
array(2) {
  ["chunk"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  ["chunk"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

(PHP VERSION 5.4.45)

Comment: The first parameter of getopt should be a string and not a array.
use the absolute path for php. After converting array('c::') to 'c::' The code works just fine on my setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php), the description of `getopt` is:

```
array getopt ( string $options [, array $longopts ] )
```

So the first parameter must be a `string` instead an `array`:

```
<?php
$options = getopt('c::', array('chunk::'));
var_dump($options);
```